# pound sign £ in bold (text mode)

Tags: formatting, symbols, bold

I'm trying to use `\pounds` in a heading that I'm making bold using `\textbf`, i.e. something like

`\textbf{NHS budget increase: \pounds{350} million a week?}`

but the £ sign doesn't come out bold.

How do I make the £ go bold?

Comment: It will be bold if the font you are using provides a bold version of the symbol.  For example the default computer modern font provides the symbol in bold.  But you have not told us enough information to diagnose.

Comment: For future readers: I hadn't added any font packages, so I suppose I was using computer modern, OT1 (7 bit) font encoding.
adding ```\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}``` in the preamble changed it to (8 bit) T1 font encoding. This had ```\pounds``` with a bold version as Steven B. Segletes claimed it would.